# phpstorm debugging with xdebug randomly skipping breakpoints when script has file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iis

While using IIS, phpstorm with xdebug, and jQuery, I'm having trouble getting phpstorm to debug my script when a file input element is included in an async form submission. Without the element, the breakpoint hits as expected, but with the file element, results vary.

I have restarted IIS and execution stopped on the breakpoint a few times, but seemingly randomly. I have switched xdebug.remote_autostart to both 0 and 1 with, again, seemingly random results.

I'm getting the same results whether submitting async or not, but here is my current javascript code:

```
var onSubmitForm = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var url = $form.attr('action');
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    xhr.success(function (res){
       //do some stuff
    });

$container.on('submit', '#my_form', onSubmitForm);
```

On submit, the breakpoint briefly hits then execution continues, ignoring any further breakpoints.

I suspect this is a php or iis problem, but I'm out of ideas. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you placing the breakpoint? Have you tried using `debugger` to use the (probably more accurate) browser dev tools instead?

Comment: Not sure I follow, please let me know if I'm off point.

I have a breakpoint first line of my php action method, as well as in a few other places in a service method called from the action. The very first breakpoint briefly hits (as in, phpstorm debug tools open, line is highlighted) but then execution continues and ignores all other breakpoints.

I'm using chrome for javacript debugging, and those all hit as expected. I have a breakpoint on the first line of onSubmitForm() and in the success callback.

Comment: in this scenario, i find i need to put lavish timeouts (php, php-fpm, ajax, etc), to have any chance of stepping the invoked php. I actually prefer not to, just dump the `formData` somewhere, and feed it in a php unit test which i can then step and debug.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Do you know why this occurs? Seems like very strange behavior... I would love to research this some more.

Comment: this problem is happening to me right now. Dont even close to find a solution.